# Pandas xlsxwriter format date column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I am creating Excel file with date column, want to format date column into `'mmm-yy'` format. some reason below code is not working.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'test_date': pd.date_range('1/1/2022', periods=12, freq='M')})

with pd.ExcelWriter('format-01.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test', index=False)
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['test']
    format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'mmm-yy'})
    worksheet.set_column('A:A', 30, format2)
```

Trying to understand why format is not working?

This give data in this format
[image]

**Expecting this format**

[image: expected]

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the `datetime_format` parameter of [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) here:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(
    'format-01.xlsx', 
    engine='xlsxwriter', 
    datetime_format='mmm-yy'
) as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test', index=False)
    worksheet = writer.sheets['test']
    worksheet.set_column('A:A', 30)
```

Comment: Is this that simple!!..Wow

Comment: @bigben I have multiple date time column want to change only one column format. Is it possible with this method?

Comment: @sfgroups I wondered if that was your setup. To be honest, I'm not sure here, would have to dig through the pandas source code.

Comment: @sfgroups - interesting lines in `ExcelWriter` code [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.0/pandas/io/excel/_base.py#L1307-L1314).

Comment: @BigBen this setting looks to be whole sheet. Thanks for sharing